# Macbookの容量がシステムデータでいっぱいになってしまう。

Tags: macos

Macbookのストレージが下記の画像のように、システムデータの部分がいっぱいになってしまいます。どのようにしたら、なくなるでしょうか?また、よく使うアプリケーションは、Xcodeです。
[image]

Comment: 「システムデータ」といっても様々ですのでこれだけではよくわかりませんね。「管理…」を押すと容量をとっているファイルが詳細に表示されますが、もう試しましたか？

Comment: そうですね。見たところ、システムデータが一番容量を食っていました

Comment: はい。その画面から「管理…」を押すと https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT206996 の上から2番目の画像のような画面が出てきて、より詳細なことがわかります。

Comment: macOS のバージョンはいくつでしょうか？

Comment: macOSのバージョンは、Montereyバージョン12.0Betaです

Comment: Big Surを使っているので、少し違うかもしれませんが、 https://otona-life.com/2021/05/10/64551/ に記載されている「ストレージのシステム容量が大きいときの対処法」とか使えないでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

実際にどのようなファイルが容量を食っているのかを調べるのが早いです。システムデータが食っているといっても、その内訳で何が大きいデータになってしまっているのかには環境や条件によって異なります。本当に必要なデータなのかもしれませんし、キャッシュのように消せるデータなのかもしれません。

まず、「このMacについて」→「ストレージ」→「管理」で出てくる「ストレージの管理」では、サイズの大きなファイルを一覧することができます。

[image: 「ストレージの管理」のスクリーンショットです。]

またサードパーティーのツールをインストールすることができるなら、いくつかツールが知られているので使ってみるのも良いでしょう。OmniDiskSweeper などいくつかのツールが知られています。こちらのリストを参考にしてください: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/5360/360444

また、ツールをインストールしなくてもコマンドラインで調べることができます。[`du`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix)) というディスク使用量を調べるコマンドがあるので、これを使って調べていけば良いです:

```sh
sudo du -h -d 1 -c -x / | sort -h
```

（ただし `/` から調べるとそれなりに時間がかかります。）

#### 関連

- [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5353/360444)
- ["System" storage on macOS Sierra is 470GB!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/261252/360444)

Comment: ありがとうございます
解決しました